# An inequality for stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, markov-chains

Consider row stochastic matrix $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^{n}$, that is, $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq 1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} = 1$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

The following inequality seems true from numerical simulations:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \min\left(a_{ik}, a_{jk}\right) \geq \underset{i\neq j}{\min}\left(a_{ii} + a_{ji}\right), \quad \text{for all} \, i\neq j.$$

The above defines ${n}\choose{2}$ inequalities, since the left-hand-side depends on the choice of the pair of rows: $i$-th and $j$-th row, $i\neq j$. The expression on the right-hand-side is a constant.

How to prove/disprove this?

Comment: Did you mean $a_{ij}+a_{ji}$ (instead of $a_{i\color{red}{i}}+a_{ji}$) In the bracketed term on the RHS? And as it stands, the displayed expression represents only **one** inequality rather than ${n}\choose{2}$. Did you mean $$\sum_{k=1}^n\min(a_{ik},a_{jk})\ge a_{ij}+a_{ji}\quad\text{ for all }i\ne j$$ instead?

Comment: @user1551: No, I meant the inequality as displayed. The RHS is constant but the LHS is not. Note that the LHS sum is over column index $k$ for each row index pair $i \neq j$. This makes it of the form LHS$(i,j) \geq$ constant, for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: If $i$ and $j$ are fixed on the LHS, you shouldn't put it under the summation sign.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality doesn't hold for general row stochastic matrices. As counterexample, consider $2\times 2$ case:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 1-\alpha\\ \beta & 1-\beta\end{pmatrix}, \quad 0\leq \alpha,\beta\leq 1.$$

Then left-hand-side (LHS) of the inequality $= \min(\alpha,\beta) + \min(1-\alpha,1-\beta)$, and right-hand-side (RHS) $= \min(\alpha+\beta,2-\alpha-\beta)$. Using the identity $\min(a,b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(a+b - |a-b|\right)$ for each pointwise minimum in the LHS and RHS, we see that

$$\text{LHS} = 1 - |\alpha - \beta|, \quad \text{RHS} = 1 - |\alpha + \beta - 1|,$$

and hence proving our inequality is equivalent to proving $|\alpha - \beta| \leq |\alpha + \beta - 1|$, which fails for example at $\alpha = 0.2$, $\beta=0.6$.

**Edit:**

More numerical simulations show that the inequality fails for $n\geq 3$ as well, although failure seems rare at higher dimensions. For example, out of 10,000 randomly generated $6\times 6$ stochastic matrices, the inequality seems to fail 1 or 2 times, i.e., failure percentage is of the order of $10^{-2}$.